# Barchart with 2 bars each group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot `mean_1` and `mean_2` separately by each value of grouping variable `x`.
Thus, I need two bars for each group.

Data:

```
n <- 100
set.seed(123)  
data <- data.frame(
  x = round(runif(n, min = 3, max = 5)),
  mean_1 = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  mean_2 = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) + 0.3)
```

Approach which just shows 1 bar:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(x))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = mean_1), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = mean_2), stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "Abs") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Thank you

Comment: You actually have a total of 200 bars split between the three x axis locations, but they are all the same color and they all overlap (add `alpha = 0.3` to each `geom_bar` call to see this more clearly). It isn't clear what you want to show here. Do you want the _average_ of `mean_1` at each x location as a single bar, and the _average_ of `mean_2` as a single bar? If so, so you want them dodged or stacked? You have added `scale_fill_manual`, but this only works if you have assigned a mapping to the `fill` aesthetic inside `aes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first make your dataset tidy by using `tidyr::pivot_longer` (or any of your favorite [reshaping approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)) then use `ggplot`, with a few tweaks to your existing code (see below)
Data

```
data_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, mean_1:mean_2, 
                                 names_to = "mean", 
                                 values_to = "value")
#       x mean     value
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     4 mean_1  0.253 
# 2     4 mean_2  1.09  
# 3     5 mean_1 -0.0285
# 4     5 mean_2  1.07  
# ....
```

To plot, use `y = value` and `fill = mean` in the `aes()`, as well as `position = position_dodge()` in `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = factor(x), y = value, fill = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",  position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "Abs") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The above plot shows the range of `mean_1` and `mean_2`, so if that’s the goal of visualization you are all set. Though, with these data, you may be better off using `geom_boxplot`, which shows several summary statistics by group via the box, whiskers, and points:

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = factor(x), y = value, fill = mean)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "x",
       y = "Abs") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

As @AllanCameron mentions, you may want to look into `... + geom_bar( stat = "summary", fun = mean, ...) + ...`, which calculates and graphs the mean of each `mean_1` and `mean_2`:

```
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = factor(x), y = value, fill = mean)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean, position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "Abs") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I wondered if perhaps the OP wanted `geom_bar` with `stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean', position = 'dodge'`?

Comment: @AllanCameron great point - I didnt see your comment above. Edited to add this as an option as well - great catch!

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you very much. I was wondering whether it functions with data being present as in my example. I appreciate that! Is it possible to set more space between each 2 bars to separate the groups a bit more? position_dodge(width = 1.5) does not work in such case.

Comment: @geek45 glad it worked! try adding `width` both inside and outside `position_dodge()` in `geom_bar` - something like `... + geom_bar(..., width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) + ....` - if that doesnt work, you may want to poke around other equations on SO or ask a new question. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith `... position_dodge(0.6), width = 0.6)` works fine.